# How can I improve my accuracy?

Tags: team-fortress-2

If I play a class, such as scout, I often have times where I was *right next to* an enemy medic, at point blank, but I miss completely and get killed.

At times like this I feel I am not credit to team.

So simply put, **how can I improve my accuracy?**

Comment: According to Heavy, only "Engineer is credit to team." Maybe that's your problem :)

Comment: Note: The Scout's accuracy for his Primary weapons is partly dependent on the server's weapon spread setting.  It defaults to random, which makes all but one pellet go in random directions (that last pellet goes straight down the sight).  The same applies to Shotguns in the game.  Pistols and Revolvers only shoot straight on the first shot regardless of the weapon spread setting, and in a random cone afterward until a certain cooldown period has passed.

Comment: Accuracy is for people who don't have miniguns. :)

Answer (score 10):

Many new players without even realizing it are using incredibly high sensitivities and have no control over their aim because of it. If this sounds like you, you'll want to lower your sensitivity as much as you can without hindering your movement. A rule of thumb is that a natural and controlled flick of your wrist should equate to a 180 degree turn in either direction.

Most professionals also suggest turning off mouse acceleration (this means the faster you move the cursor the more it will move, rather than being linear). This can be done in Control Panel --> Mouse --> Pointer Options --> Enhance Pointer Precision. It should be off.

After you've done this, stick with the sensitivity for at least 8-10 hours of playtime- you're going to be terrible with the change at first. If you still can't stand the sensitivity, you might want to consider tweaking it again, but don't get stuck in a pattern where you change every few weeks and never become accustomed to one. Pick something reasonable, get used to it, and you'll see improvement.

Answer (score 5):

Late answer - but here it goes. I used to try and play FPS using my touch pad at first (Sucked at it) so dropped FPS totally. Then I tried with a crappy <300 dpi mouse - again sucked - but slightly better.

Then I bought a high end mouse (Very worth the investment) - and bam - top 3 everytime in TF2. Your problem might be similar - you might have the necessary reflexes, but the bad quality hardware might be punishing you. Upgrade!

Answer (score 4):

Practice.

That is all.

in some extream cases maybe play around with your mouse sensitivity settings and see if that helps you at all... but mainly Practice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, practice, practice, but if that doesn't help you out, try tweaking the mouse sensitivity and acceleration a bit. A good sensitivity is 75 percent for new players.