# What can I do to ensure the tightest spread possible?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When I'm playing CS:GO competitively, I often happen to spectate team players who fire 1 or two shots in nice even bursts, and completely destroy enemies.  I am unable to replicate this, however, even if I use 2burst shots, my shots tend to go wild, and the crosshairs go wild as well.

Are there any "professional" tips to ensure a super tight spread of the crosshairs? I'd love to polish my aiming skills, it's pretty lackluster now.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=aBeNsy7UsSY#t=119s

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=IO_KWGF_AgQ#t=117s

Comment: Right, but I want to know how I can improve it overall with any weapon, not just the class usuals

Comment: Aim better. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/how-can-i-improve-my-accuracy/27422#27422

Comment: Not necessarily, I'm asking how to decrease the spread shown via the crosshairs.

Comment: Use the bullseye spray paint. Spray a wall. Stand back and shoot at the wall in different ways to notice how the gun reacts. Each gun reacts differently so try it out on all of the guns you wish to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cl_observercrosshair "0"

This isn't going to help you aim better, though, it's just a preference thing. If your 2-shot bursts aren't accurate you're probably moving when you fire. You need to stop before firing to make your shots accurate; you can start moving again after firing.

All of the crosshair variables: http://www.pro-hl.com/columns/csgo_crosshairs.php

Comment: So does crouching or walking change the accuracy or anything? Is it better if I just stop whenever I need to shoot someone?

Comment: Crouching improves accuracy slightly but is usually not worth it, and moving decreases accuracy significantly. These variables are all unique to each gun, but in general SMG's and pistols are the only time you can get away with spraying while running. The idea with rifles is to strafe back and forth, stopping at various times to fire controlled 2-3 shot bursts. The two videos I posted in top-level comments show this. For specific variables, you can see various spreadsheets here that are kept updated: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuOy-5I1VcBMdGZmYndxUjctc1VNUDZHTXJFUE9Dbmc#gid=0

Comment: Why don't you edit this into your answer :D

Comment: Because it's not what your question asks. =o

Comment: Well, I did ask how to get the tightest spread.  If crouching improves accuracy, meaning a smaller spread, doesn't that answer it? Regardless, it's a good answer, thanks.